# Flutter windows build: Nuget is not installed

Tags: windows, flutter, nuget, desktop

I uninstalled Visual Studio 2019 and installed it as 2022.

I reinstalled Flutter.
When building Flutter desktop, the following problem is repeated.

If I run it in another project, it works without any problem.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
Building Windows application...
Nuget is not installed.
Nuget.exe not found, trying to download or use cached version.
```

Answer (score 25):

try this, worked for me

1. (Windows 10 v1709 or greater) Run "winget install Microsoft.NuGet" as administrator and restart VSCode
2. if didn't work yet download nugget.exe from https://www.nuget.org/downloads and then put it in your windows/system32 folder and restart VSCode

Comment: Followed method 2, and then run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` has solved my problem.

Comment: Method 1 solved my problem after quitting VS Code and relaunching it ("Reload window" was not sufficient)

Answer (score 8):

1- make sure you have installed Visual Studio

2-

> NuGet Package Manager (PM UI and PM Console) is included with Visual
> Studio. The latest NuGet releases are delivered as part of Visual
> Studio updates.

**HOWEVER**: nuget.exe itself is not included with any version of Visual Studio.

so you need to download the latest `NuGet Windows x86 Commandline` from https://www.nuget.org/downloads

3- put it inside the flutter sdk folder or any folder you like

4- copy the folder path

5- in windows serach, search for env so you can put it as **system variables**. edit **path** with a new line and past the folder path

6- restart android studio

7- *congrats*

there's a video on youtube for the exact steps:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5b5sj6mG8M

Answer (score 3):

Although I don't know why it would work without this error message on the same machine, I recently ran into this issue as well. The way I fixed it was to download the [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) executable and add it to my path.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).